# Automounting sshfs with fstab, using passphrase-protected private key

Tags: linux, private-key, sshfs, fstab

I connect to my home server with `ssh server`, where server is configured in `~/.ssh/config` as:

```
Host server
    HostName {server-address}
    User me
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

`IdentityFile` is a passphrase-protected private key, so I have to enter my passphrase every time I log in.

I can locally mount the remote file system on that server with `sshfs me@{server-address}:/home/me /mnt/server`. Once again, I have to enter my passphrase to log in with my private key. I notice that I don't need to actually specify the key in the `sshfs` options - presumably `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is just the default location?

Finally, to easily mount the system, I added the below line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
me@{server-address}:/home/me  /mnt/server  fuse.sshfs  IdentityFile=/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa,defaults,noauto 0 0
```

And this lets me simply run `mount /mnt/server` to mount the filesystem - and of course, I'm asked for my passphrase.

Note that I had added the `noauto` option so that it wouldn't be mounted on boot, as I was worried the system would hang if it couldn't mount the filesystem without the passphrase.

Is my suspicion right here? Will the system fail to boot if it tried to mount the server filesystem, but didn't get the passphrase? Is there a way that I can supply the passphrase to `/etc/fstab` / the `mount` command, so that it will be able to boot the filesystem on boot?

Comment: Take a look at this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29250/sshfs-always-asking-for-password-in-fstab

Comment: @Philippe thanks, not exactly what I'm looking for (the answers either deal with private keys with no passphrase, or using regular passwords), but I might be able to use some of that info. I'll add an answer myself if I get sorted.

Comment: Have you looked this answer : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/348060/387273

Comment: That answer seems to use `sshpass` to automate supplying a password, rather than a private-key passphrase. I'll look into it though, and see if it can be changed around for a private-key.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm afraid not, had no luck with using `sshpass` within my `/etc/fstab`. I ended up just leaving the `noauto` option on, and just mounting the remote drive with `sudo mount /mnt/server` (which requires me to specify passphrase) whenever I needed it. One command and a passphrase isn't putting me out too much, especially since I don't need that server mounted all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this "solution" warrants an answer, but here is how I got around it:

I simply used `ssh-keygen` to generate another key (i.e. `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_no_passphrase`) and didn't give that one a passphrase. Then I used `ssh-copy-id` to upload it to my remote server.
After changing my fstab entry to reference the new public key in the `IdentityFile`-field it worked flawlessly and now automatically mounts the filesystem on boot.

Here is the final fstab entry:

```
# sshfs
USER@SERVER:/home/sshfs /mnt/ssh    fuse.sshfs  defaults,_netdev,allow_other,default_permissions,identityfile=/home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa_no_passphrase,uid=UID,gid=GID    0   0
```

It might not be an exact solution to the problem, but it seems to be a valid workaround!

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 20.04 server, this worked for me (step by step)

install sshfs

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

i created the key pair (without passphare), and copy it to remote server

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id REMOTE_USER@REMOTE_SERVER
```

add this line in /etc/fstab (thanks to @Sealad), replace all uppercase

```
REMOTE_USER@REMOTE_SERVER:/home/me  /mnt/server    fuse.sshfs  defaults,_netdev,allow_other,default_permissions,identityfile=/home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa,uid=UID,gid=GID    0   0
```

use this to get UID and GID

```
id -u USER
id -g USER
```

and do this only once (it should ask you for remote password)

```
sudo mount -a
```

reboot your system to  check

Answer (score -1):

I would like to give an alternative to the only answer in this question. Instead of creating a new keypair (this time without protecting the private key), it is possible to remove a passphrase from the existing private key.

Just do `$ ssh-keygen -p`. After removing the password, sshfs in fstab works flawlessly.

My final sshfs fstab like is
USER@SERVER:/folder /mnt/sshfsmount fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,allow_other,IdentityFile=/home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa,reconnect,follow_symlinks 0 0